# Jwt Token arrives as Null SignalR

Tags: .net, jwt, .net-6.0, bearer-token, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm working in a Notifications Service using **SignalR** in **.net 6.0**.
I need to get data user through a token by query, however, it arrives like null.
I don't find more information and I don't know what else to do.

My Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(o =>
{
    o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        //ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        // ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],

        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey
            (Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["secreatKey"])),
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = false,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true
    };

    o.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnMessageReceived = context =>
        {
            var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) == false)
            {
                context.Token = accessToken;
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});
```

My Hub:

```
public class NotificationHub : Hub<INotificationHub>
{
    //Crea la Conexion

    private readonly NotificationMemoryStorage _notificationStorage;

    public NotificationHub(NotificationMemoryStorage notificationMemoryStorage)
    {
        _notificationStorage = notificationMemoryStorage;
    }

    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        
        var userId = GetUserIdFromToken();
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
        {
            var notifications = _notificationStorage.GetNotifications(userId);
            foreach (var notification in notifications)
            {
                await Clients.User(userId).SendNotification(notification);
            }
            _notificationStorage.ClearNotifications(userId);
            var response = new ServerResponse
            {
                status = "Acepted",
            };
            await Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).ConnectionResponse(response);

        }
            await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception? exception)
    {
        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }

    public async Task MessageCheck(NotificationRequestModel request)
    {
        //meter validaciones
        switch (request.Target.Device)
        {
            case "Admin":
                if (request.Target.User.Contains("*"))
                {
                    SendNotificationToAllUsers(request.Notification);
                }
                else
                {
                    //SendNotificationToSpecificUser(request, request.Target.User);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    //Desconecta del Servidor
    public async Task SendNotificationToAllUsers(NotificationModel message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendNotificationToAllUsers(message);
    }
    private string GetUserIdFromToken()
    {
        var token = Context.GetHttpContext();
        var jwt = token.Request.Headers["access_token"];

        var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)Context.User.Identity;
        var userIdClaim = identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        return userIdClaim?.Value;
    }

    //public async Task SendNotificationToSpecificUser(NotificationRequestModel message, List<string> target)
    //{
    //    foreach (var item in target)
    //    {
    //        //if (ConnectedUsers.TryGetValue(item, out var user))
    //        //{
    //        await Clients.Client(user.ConnectionId).SendNotification(message);
    //        //}
    //    }
    //}
}
```

In here the data arrives as null:

```
private string GetUserIdFromToken()`enter code here`
        {
            var token = Context.GetHttpContext();
            var jwt = token.Request.Headers["access_token"];
    
            var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)Context.User.Identity;
            var userIdClaim = identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            return userIdClaim?.Value;
        }
```

Attach Image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RElrr.png)

I recognize I don't know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some minor issues along the way, try it like this

**Step 1:**

Remove bearer-prefix from the querystring request

`?access_token=bearerXXXX` --> `?access_token=XXXX`

**Step 2:**

Read the token from the query and apply the token and a bearer-prefix with a space to the authorization header in the OnMessageReceived event

```
OnMessageReceived = context =>
{
    var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
    {
        context.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
    }

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

**Step 3:**

Enforce the authorization on your hub by adding the Authorize-attribute to the class

```
[Authorize]
public class NotificationHub : Hub<INotificationHub>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, we should get token like this way.

```
string jwt = Context.GetHttpContext().Request.Query["access_token"];
```

Second, we should us `jwt.io` site to check the jwt token.

[image]

Then we can use below code to get the id like below:

```
private string GetUserIdFromToken()
{
    // for getting the token
    // no need in your production
    string jwt = Context.GetHttpContext().Request.Query["access_token"];

    var identity = Context.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    var userIdClaim = identity.FindFirst("id"); 
    return userIdClaim?.Value;
}
```

The `id` in my code just for test, you can verify your token first and get the value by the key. It should be work.

If userIdClaim  still null in

```
  `var userIdClaim = identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);`
```

Then we need to make sure `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` exist in your token.